# How can I add a watermark to a Gitbook book?

Tags: gitbook

Is there a way to add a watermark to a book generated with [Gitbook](https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook)? Ideally to every page in a given section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to add a watermark to a book generated with the Gitbook.

I think the only possibility is to add watermarks with a tool after you generated the gitbook.

Comment: Yeah, I had to use Adobe Acrobat to do it.